# Why does Git add trailing TAB to the "+++ b/" line of the diff when the file name contains spaces?

Tags: git, patch, git-diff

This is more an idle curiosity question but I've just discovered that Git adds TABs to the names of files containing spaces in `git-diff` output. E.g.

```
$ git init test
$ cd test
$ echo 'test' > 'file with spaces'
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Add'
$ git show | grep '<literal-TAB-here>' | od -c
0000000   +   +   +       b   /   f   i   l   e       w   i   t   h    
0000020   s   p   a   c   e   s  \t  \n
0000030
```

Why does it do this and is there some way to prevent this from happening? Using `-z` option and/or setting `core.quotepath = false` doesn't change this behaviour.

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/main/diff.c#L1479), it seems designed.

Comment: The [commit](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/3ee8b7bfe403f8c0c566a6963f7377a0ae98011e) message may give a clue.

Comment: This commit just refactors things, the code for printing TAB had been there before it already, but git-blame does point to [that commit](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/1a9eb3b9d50) whose message explains why it does it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @ElpieKay I found the answer to my own question in the commit message of [this commit](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/1a9eb3b9d50) which says

> It is because GNU patch expects to find TAB (and trailing timestamp)
> on ---/+++ (old_name and new_name) lines after the filenames.

This, of course, just begs the question of why does GNU patch expect to find a TAB in this case and the best answer to this I have is that it comes from patch 2.5.6 (imported in GNU patch repository in the 712cce6fdd396508038dde727f3b1d41d3bb3f61 back in 2009 but actually released in 2002, apparently) which added the following comment:

```c
/* Allow file names with internal spaces,
   but only if a tab separates the file name from the date.
*/
```

Comment: So the missing note I was talking about is the trailing timestamp, then. TIL, thanks for hunting it down.

Comment: Yes, it's probably worth explaining this, so I've updated my answer with this information, thanks.

Comment: Thinking about it, I think GNU patch is being subtler than that code comment gives it credit for: it's expecting a whitespace-separated trailer on that line to be a timestamp, probably allowing normal spaces for that because of an even older diff implementation, for paths with embedded spaces it looks for a tab trailer to disambiguate. .... yup: at least GNU's diff puts tab-separated timestamp trailers on the path lines.

Answer (score 3):

`git diff` and `git status` and `git show` are "porcelain", human-convenience commands with output that's been postprocessed for human consumption. I expect the tab is there as a separator for notes that turn out to be empty here.

If you want the just-the-facts-ma'am diff, use the core command, the "plumbing":

```
git diff-tree -p @
```

where `-p` says you want the patch, not just differing ids, and `@` is there because core commands have very few defaults, you say exactly what you want and they do that. For instance, `git diff` notices if you're diffing a root commit and supplies an ersatz empty base tree to diff against, for your example situation, a root commit, with nothing to compare against, you actually have to supply an empty tree to compare against:

```
git diff-tree -p `git hash-object --stdin -t tree <&-` @
```

(personally I think `git diff-tree` should have supplied an empty parent to diff against for root commits automatically, the way `git diff` does, but it's waayyyyy too late to change that now, because production scripts are allowed to rely on the exact behavior of core commands).

Comment: Thanks, I understand the difference between `git-diff` and `git-diff-tree`, I was just curious _why_ git-diff was doing it and the real answer is that it's for compatibility with GNU patch. P.S. But this does answer the second part of the question, about how to avoid it, thanks (it's just that in my particular case it's really more trouble than it's worth it to use something other than `git-diff`...).